# HTML Page Size - page weight

Tags: html, size, filesize

I have to measure the over all page size of all the pages on my company's intrAnet site.

Please let me know how I can measure / calculate it.

Expectation : I open the intrAnet page in IE/Firefox. After it is completely loaded, the tool or utility should give me the complete size of page.

*PS : Complete size of page means :Accumulative size of html, used images, css, scripts, flash files etc.*

If I **save the complete page** on my desktop then it does not save the flash files and other images which are getting called through Java script, thats why I am not able to calculate the web page size.

Please reply soon.

regds
Vivek

Answer (score 5):

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) will give you the size of all downloaded elements, including flash objects! For measurements you should be able to use it!

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution: use Firebug's Net tab while reloading with Shift+Reload. [Firebug can be downloaded here](http://getfirebug.com/) and installs as an extension to Firefox. You can open it using the bug icon in the bottom-right corner. Choose the Net tab, then click on its arrow and choose 'Enabled'. Navigate to the page you want to measure (you might have to reopen Firebug), then hold the Shift key while clicking the Reload button. The Net tab shows the weight of all the files being downloaded and the cumulative weight as the last line in the log.

Answer (score 1):

[GetLeft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getleftdown/) is able to grab a complete site structure onto hard disk. You'll have to do some fine-tuning to get the exact result but it should work.

If you're doing things like adding scripts dynamically using JavaScript, you'll probably be out of luck - stuff like this is almost impossible to count. I think your best bet in such a case would be the "Document size" page in Firefox's [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/).

Answer (score 1):

Warning: note that "Page info" on Firefox does only give you the size of the html, and does not include the size of the images and other medias contained in the page. 
This can be verified by going into the Media menu once you've asked the Page information panel.

Answer (score -1):

With Firefox, click on the "Tools" pull-down and then select the "Page Info" option.

The information of the current page will be displayed. This includes the page size in KB (and bytes).